# Same columns height in flex model is not being applied

Tags: html, css

I need to create a 1x4 layout that changes to 2x2 layout when width is less than 600px:

```css
.group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  flex: 25%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .block {
    flex: 50%;
  }
}

.main, .block {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="group">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>       

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>   

</div>
```

I need the columns to be of the same height but they are not.

I need `border` class to be applied `text` div and all to be same height.

How to do this?

Comment: Try `.group {align-items: stretch;}`

Comment: Both `.main` and `.text` need `height: 100%` as they are not flex child elements, only `.block` is.

Comment: @drak It does not work

Comment: @RenevanderLende They get extended but somehow when I have 2 rows one of the borders gets over text

Comment: why all those nested divs?

Comment: Actually, ignore my previous comment, as it indeed only does half the job. You only need to add `.main, .block { display: flex }` and it will work as expected (just checked it). You problem is that you seem to assume that flexbox works at any nested child level. It does not, just one level deep.

Comment: Check my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/ExpXeVd). It shows a main app, with three Codepens openend in iframes. All showing some sort of flexbox use. My codepen with [your code](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/MWzydVR).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a grid

```css
.group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / repeat(4, 1fr);
  row-gap: 20px;  /* Adjust for padding in .text */
}

.block,
.main {
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .group {
    grid-template: 1fr 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.text {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```